# How to get value in my label when click on tableview or button

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

Hi, I am trying to show name and email from SQLite in a label from `tableView` to next view, but in my log message I only get name and label name, label email are null.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell =[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
    if (cell==nil) {
        cell =[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault 
                                    reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
    }
    cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    user *worddc=[Array objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    cell.textLabel.text = worddc.name;
    profileVC *pvc =[[profileVC alloc]init];

    NSLog(@"name is  %@",worddc.name);

    pvc.nameLbl.text=worddc.name;

    NSLog(@"email is  %@",worddc.email);
    NSLog(@"label name is %@",pvc.nameLbl.text);

    pvc.emailLbl.text=worddc.email;

    NSLog(@"label email is %@",pvc.emailLbl.text);

    return cell;
}
```

in log message:

```
2012-12-07 17:02:28.720 loginApp[1881:c07] CONNECTION SUCCESSFUL WITH DB
2012-12-07 17:02:36.628 loginApp[1881:c07] QUERY: select email,password from login where email ='a@a.com' and password ='a'
2012-12-07 17:02:36.664 loginApp[1881:c07] QUERY: SELECT login.Name,login.id,login.Email FROM login ORDER BY login.Name ASC, login.id ASC
2012-12-07 17:02:36.667 loginApp[1881:c07] QUERY: select last_insert_rowid() 
2012-12-07 17:02:38.010 loginApp[1881:c07] id 6 
2012-12-07 17:02:38.011 loginApp[1881:c07] name is  a
2012-12-07 17:02:38.011 loginApp[1881:c07] email is  (null)
2012-12-07 17:02:38.012 loginApp[1881:c07] label name is (null)
2012-12-07 17:02:38.017 loginApp[1881:c07] label email is (null)
```

Any help or suggestion please?

Comment: Without sample of code where you create array of objects `user` it's impossible to predict where the problem is.
You have to also change your style of coding: class names should start from upper letter (`User` not `user`, `ProfileVC` not `profileVC`). Object names should start from lower letter, or from underscore.
Your current style is misleading.

Comment: when execute query in program

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to load the view controller from a nib? If so you need to call – initWithNibName:bundle: on profileVC instead of just init.

Comment: Yes, you can pass nil as the bundle and it'll look in the main bundle. Do you have a nib for profileVC? If so, make sure the outlets are connected in the nib.

Comment: all things are ok..yes i have nib file also and outlets are connected

Comment: Can you log the labels themselves as well as the tex to make sure it's not nil?

Comment: i get the name when i click on cell of tableview in my log message wbut when do not i get value of email?

Answer (score 0):

You should implement the `profileVC` calling method in `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath:` because `cellForRowAtIndexPath` will call everytime upto number of rows in your database and  your are initializing the pvc in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` which in every loop the scope of pvc is out of range. so Implement this call in

```
profileVC *pvc =[[profileVC alloc]init];

NSLog(@"name is  %@",worddc.name);

pvc.nameLbl.text=worddc.name;

NSLog(@"email is  %@",worddc.email);
NSLog(@"label name is %@",pvc.nameLbl.text);

pvc.emailLbl.text=worddc.email;

NSLog(@"label email is %@",pvc.emailLbl.text);
```

Answer (score 0):

Is worddc valid (not nil)? How about Array?

Answer (score 0):

profileVC *pvc =[[profileVC alloc]init]; it create & allocate newly in class when you allocate  new views the all valus are null it only loads view did load and load view not load other methods